# Are there any good Discrete Mathematics video online?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, online-resources

I want to learn discrete mathematics by reading book by myself but I find sometime it's very hard to understand what author trying to say.

I want to know, are there any good online video that teach discrete mathematic?

Comment: Discrete mathematics is a bit of a broad, and well I dare say ill-defined concept. Some of the things that can fall under the concept are combinatorics, graph theory, theory of sequences (like solving of recursion equations), some number theory, discrete dynamical systems, discrete probability, etc... Maybe you want to be more specific.

Comment: You could search here: http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm

Comment: This course is promising: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-315-combinatorial-theory-introduction-to-graph-theory-extremal-and-enumerative-combinatorics-spring-2005/

Answer (score 9):

Check out the free audio/video courses in mathematics available through MIT OpenCourseWare: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/audio-video-courses/#mathematics

Answer (score 6):

I found these ones:

- [Arsdigita](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-2965569821331370765) (Google Video)
- [Skienna](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/math-video/) (Stony Brook University)
- [Discrete Mathematics](http://www.aduni.org/courses/discrete/index.php?view=cw) (ADUni.org)

Another list is here: [More Free Mathematics Video Courses](http://freescienceonline.blogspot.com/2008/10/more-free-mathematics-video-courses.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use ocw. 
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/index.htm

It's an excellent course with video lectures and readings for someone just starting out to study university level discrete mathematics; especially in relation to computer science. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is an actual course in Discrete Mathematics, more specifically: Mathematics for Computer Science from the MIT OpenCourseWare -> [Mathematics for Computer Science - 6.042J / 18.062J](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/)

Answer (score 1):

Introduction to higher mathematics covers many topics from discrete math.
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZzHxk_TPOStgPtqRZ6KzmkUQBQ8TSWVX
Discrete mathematical structures is harder to understand but is very comprehensive.
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0862D1A947252D20

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** Shameless self-promotion.

Discrete Math Playlist: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtxJg53s2o0OcotIx1_uKY0gEjqq96sx6

Combinatorial Optimization Playlist: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtxJg53s2o0PqIAEphtjIaqXTouaWYR0j

These are videos from two university courses in Discrete Math that I've taught in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Try Math Doctor Bob on Youtube. He talks a lot about discrete maths

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Full video lecture in discrete math. This course have recenlty taken in university of colorodo. Good luck----  - http://cmes.uccs.edu/Fall2012/Math215/archive.php

Answer (score 0):

Kim Brehm has some amazing courses on YouTube

Discrete Math 1 (mainly logic) - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-gb0E4MII28GykmtuBXNUNoej-vY5Rz

Discrete Math 2 (mainly combinatorics) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spEjNcd37IQ&list=PLl-gb0E4MII0sGLCJeqDB3y63HZ6lM5LJ