# Study regimen for discrete mathematics? - Lack high-school maths...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education, self-learning, learning, online-resources

I have just gotten into college, and will be studying mathematics from next semester. ([this course](http://handbook.mq.edu.au/2013/Units/UGUnit/DMTH137))

Unfortunately I did not study mathematics for the last [2-3 years of high-school mathematics](http://australiancurriculum.edu.au/SeniorSecondary/Mathematics/Mathematical-Methods/Curriculum/SeniorSecondary).

What should I study for the next 50 days in preparation for [the course](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/DMTH137s212)?

Comment: Get the books and syllabi for the courses you will take first semester and start studying on your own. Try to bring yourself to the point that when the course starts you are 2 or 3 weeks ahead of class. Try to maintain the lead.

Comment: Great suggestion, will attempt to do just that. I have the [textbook for the course](http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Kenneth-Rosen/dp/0073229725), however it's not the easiest medium to follow. Might grab Schaum's book (as suggested); however am concerned that it will be just as difficult to follow :/

Comment: There are many online courses you can sample to see [MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/index.htm) that would be an advanced version; and check answers to a similar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23407/are-there-any-good-discrete-mathematics-video-online)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Schaum's Outline Series" volume on "Discrete Mathematics"](http://www.powells.com/biblio/61-9780071615860-0) is pretty good and seems to match the course description you linked to.  It was written with this sort of purpose in mind.  It has lots of problems, with solutions.  It's also cheap.

Comment: Thanks, also wondering if there was something more interactive, like a MOOC or something?

Comment: The book has arrived!

Comment: I hope it works well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Buy "TTC", now known as The Great Courses.

Check out [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org).

http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/video.php?subjectId=106106094 - this is a little bit based on programming

https://www.youtube.com/user/coursehack/videos?flow=grid&view=1 - this has discrete math 1 & 2

And yes use schaum's outlines. They are really good.

And buy the solution manual for the text you might use to help you practice.