# Are there any good free online courses on discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I'm a junior in HS and I want to learn discrete math. I know calculus topics (took calc ab this year) and I want to major in CS so, I wanted to explore math fields that are useful to learn for CS. Discrete math is apparently one such topic. So, are there any good free online courses that focus on discrete math and possibly provide a certificate/proof of completion? thanks.

(if not free, then a small fee would work)

Comment: I recommend googling for "discrete math pdf", and then finding and downloading a suitable pdf.  I further recommend that you find one that seems comfortable to you, and that has a **lot of exercises** to attack.  Personally, I learn more from the exercises, which force me to apply the theory, than by reading about the theory.  Coupled with this approach, I also recommend using mathSE as a crutch for problems that you can't solve.

Comment: See [Are there any good Discrete Mathematics video online?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23407/are-there-any-good-discrete-mathematics-video-online?rq=1)